# Retrieve distinct value where only another value exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains a list of DocIds, Tasks, StartDate, and EndDate, as shown. I need to build a query which returns only DocIds where 'Task A' has a NOT NULL EndDate, AND no other Tasks.

```
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
| DocId | Task | StartDate | EndDate  |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
|     1 | A    | 1/1/2017  | 1/1/2017 |
|     2 | A    | 1/1/2017  | 1/2/2017 |
|     2 | B    | 1/2/2017  | 1/3/2017 |
+-------+------+-----------+----------+
```

If this were my entire table, the query would return the DocId from the first row only, because it is a DocId with only Task A which has an EndDate, and no Task B.

I have started with something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DocId
    FROM WorkTasks
    WHERE [Task] = 'A'
    AND EndDate IS NOT NULL
    -- AND TASK(B..C..D..etc) DOES NOT EXIST
```

I am having  trouble understanding how to specify that additional tasks do not exist for a given DocId. The additional tasks are arbitrarily named, so I need to exclude any instance of a DocID which has any Task other than A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the `DocId` and take only those having only one Task with **no** other conditions than you mentioned

```
SELECT DocId
FROM WorkTasks
GROUP BY DocId
HAVING count(distinct [Task]) = 1
   AND sum(case when [Task] <> 'A' OR EndDate IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```